# I get a "Location attributes must be specified in pairs" error in a crash report when I try to open the Storyboard in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

After Updating my project from a repository, something went wrong and now XCode 6.3 crashes when I try to open the Storyboard.
According to the Crash report, the problem is due to some constraint conflict:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs
```

Great, now how do I fix that if I cannot open the storyboard in the First Place??? (Duh! Apple can you be more specific?!) There is a bunch of constraints I could delete manually by opening the storyboard in a text editor, but that would destroy my project and the crash report does not point out anything either..

I also get this on the crash report, but I cannot make any sense of it, it cant even be copied properly:

```
UserInfo: {
    IBAbstractPlatformToolExceptionBacktraceKey = "  0. CoreFoundation           0x000000010f5c6c4d __exceptionPreprocess\n  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x000000010e365bb7 objc_exception_throw\n  2. CoreFoundation           0x000000010f5c6b9d +[NSException raise:format:]\n  3. Foundation               0x000000010e08e233 VerifyConstraintArguments\n  4. Foundation               0x000000010def7a5a +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]\n  5. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da71ebc -[IBLayoutConstraint generateNSLayoutConstraintWithContext:constraintClass:]\n  6. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da51c3f -[IBAutolayoutEngine representedConstraintBySubstitutingRealViewsForRepresentedViewsOfConstraint:]\n  7. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da51d85 -[IBAutolayoutEngine addRepresentedConstraintForRealConstraint:]\n  8. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da53eeb -[IBAutolayoutEngine _attemptToAddConstraint:toView:returningConstraintsOrConstraintAbstractionsMakingSystemOverConstrained:constraintsOrAbstractionsForRepresentedConstraintsBlock:]\n  9. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da5429d -[IBAutolayoutEngine attemptToAddConstraint:toView:returningConstraintsMakingSystemOverConstrained:]\n 10. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da28011 +[IBAutolayoutArbiter attemptToAddConstraint:byModifyingLayoutEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraintBreakageStrategy:mutableConstraintsToAdd:mutableConstraintsToRemove:]\n 11. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da5251e -[IBAutolayoutEngine performEngineBootstrappingConstraintAdditionOperationForAddingConstraint:]\n 12. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da52aa4 __90-[IBAutolayoutEngine iterateViewsAndGenerateRepresentedConstraintsAndMapToRealConstraints]_block_invoke662\n 13. CoreFoundation           0x000000010f4fe925 __NSDictionaryEnumerate\n 14. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da52826 -[IBAutolayoutEngine iterateViewsAndGenerateRepresentedConstraintsAndMapToRealConstraints]\n 15. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da4d10f -[IBAutolayoutEngine initWithArbitrationUnit:options:]\n 16. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010da33827 -[IBAutolayoutArbitrationUnit computeStatus]\n 17. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x000000010be8ada1 -[IBCocoaTouchTool computeAutolayoutStatusForRequest:document:]\n 18. IBFoundation             0x000000010db9550f __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke\n 19. IBFoundation             0x000000010db952a6 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]\n 20. IBFoundation             0x000000010db94f90 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke\n 21. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000112b83964 _dispatch_client_callout\n 22. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000112b70818 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke\n 23. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000112b83964 _dispatch_client_callout\n 24. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000112b6ea59 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF\n 25. CoreFoundation           0x000000010f52e1f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__\n 26. CoreFoundation           0x000000010f4efdcb __CFRunLoopRun\n 27. CoreFoundation           0x000000010f4ef366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific\n 28. Foundation               0x000000010df1bf92 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]\n 29. IBFoundation             0x000000010db73c20 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:]\n 30. IBFoundation             0x000000010db73daf -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingSocket:]\n 31. IBFoundation             0x000000010db74072 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main]\n 32. ???                      0x000000010be0dbe7 ???\n 33. libdyld.dylib            0x0000000112bb3145 start";
}
Hints: None
```